# Excel UDF works when called through sub but always returns 0 in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, udf

My function is always returning 0 when called in a worksheet but returns proper values when called through a sub.

This function searches through a worksheet (sheetname) to see if the input value can be found in any of the columns, and if so returns the value in row 1 of the column.

```
'test sub
Sub test()
    MsgBox custCat("SUNTRUST BANK")
End Sub


Public Function custCat(toSearch)
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = "LookupValues"
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim colLtr As String
    Dim j As Integer

    'find last column
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    lastColumn = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    'loop through columns
    Do While i <= lastColumn
        'find last row
        lastRow = Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Worksheets(sheetName).Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

        'search through column
        j = 2
        Do While j <= lastRow
            If InStr(UCase(toSearch), UCase(Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(j, i).Value)) > 0 Then
                If custCat = "" Then
                    custCat = Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(1, i).Value
                Else
                    custCat = custCat & ", " & Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(1, i).Value
                End If
                j = lastRow 'exit loop if found
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: instead of `j=lastRow` (where you will still loop through again since you check for `<=`) use `Exit Do`. Also have you tried using `Debug.Print` to see, if your last column and row are set correct?

Comment: `SpecialCells` can't be used reliably in a UDF

Comment: Removing `SpecialCells` made it work, Thank you @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code a bit and made a few adjustments, try this:

```
Public Function custCat(toSearch)

    Dim i&, j&, lastRow&, lastColumn&
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("LookupValues")

    With ws

        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        i = 1
    'loop through columns
        Do While i <= lastColumn
            'find last row
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

            'search through column
            j = 2
            Do While j <= lastRow
                If InStr(UCase(toSearch), UCase(.Cells(j, i).Value)) > 0 Then
                    If custCat = "" Then
                        custCat = .Cells(1, i).Value
                    Else
                        custCat = custCat & ", " & .Cells(1, i).Value
                    End If
                    Exit Do 'exit loop if found
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            i = i + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting application-defined or object-defined error on the line: lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row